# What's the best way to normalize between two lists using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Given two IEnumerable instances in C# (call them a and b), what's the best way to remove all values in a that are not in b and add all values of b that are not in a?

I know I could just set a = b, normally, but this is ultimately for persisting to the DB via Entity Framework CodeFirst in an MVC application so there's some wonkiness of state to watch out for.  In fact, we're talking about updating a record based on stuff posted from the client.

The closest that seems to work involves about for foreach loops, one to iterate the 'a' list and populate a collection of 'items to be removed', another to iterate the 'b' list to identify the 'items to be added', and then one each on the 'items to be removed' and 'items to be added' collections to add and remove items, respectively (since you can't modify the 'a' collection while you're iterating on it.

That feels clunky, though; is there a better way?

*UPDATE*
For clarity, I'll make an example.  Let's say I have an entity I fetch from the DB which represents a blog Post (since that example never gets tired...) and said Post has a collection of Tags.  From the client, I get a list of Tags that should be now the 'canonical' list of tags, but none of them are entities, it's just an in-memory collection.  What I want to do is ensure that Post.Tags matches the tags being posted by the client, without creating duplicate tags in the database.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the set operations (`Enumerable.Except`, `Enumerable.Union`, `Enumerable.Intersect`).  The problem is your question has kinda confusing wording.  I'm not sure exactly what it is that you want to return... a single list?  or two lists?  You say "remove all the values in a that are not in b"... and "add all values of b that are not in a".  Okay,  remove them from which?  add them to which?  If you can clean up your language it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry, editing for clarity

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Intersect`, `Concat` and `Except`:

```
a = a.Intersect(b).Concat(b.Except(a));
```

`Intersect` returns items that exist in both collections, so `a.Intersect(b)` will give you all items that are in `a` and `b`.

`Except` returns elements that are in first collection, but not in the other, so `b.Except(a)` returns elements that are in `b` but not in `a`.

`Concat` concatenates these two collections.

But I don't really get your questions, so I'm not sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: that's mostly what I was looking for, I think the only wrinkle is that one of the lists is a list of Entities fetched from the DB using EF, while the other is not, so I need to do a comparison that takes that into account, while I believe your example would compare the objects for equality based on memory address.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work. I get an exception that only primitive types are permitted in the context.

Comment: You should try using your PK only, instead of entire objects.

Comment: That doesn't solve the need to finally go through the Tags on the main object and add/remove.  I ended up doing it with multiple foreach loops.  Which works, but isn't as elegant as your inmemory example

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your enumerable `a` is actually a list, so I did it this way:

```
var a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, };
var b = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 5, };

foreach (var x in a.Except(b).ToArray())
{
    a.Remove(x);
}

foreach (var x in b.Except(a).ToArray())
{
    a.Add(x);
}
```

At the end `a` has the same elements as `b`.

However, you need to be careful if you have duplicates in `b`.